# Want to Add Dynamic WebView according to Login detail in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

```
I am going through various links on this topic. But I haven't found anything 
useful in my case. I want to create a WebView in Android dynamically. From 
Android app login is done but after that according to login ID how to fetch 
dynamic URL in WebView?
```

like

```
    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    pbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("https://xyz.in");
```

in place of "https://xyz.in", I want to pass Id or anything according to login person. In my app different login person have different dashboard/navigation drawer. so how to fetch that particular dynamic URL?
I am using PHP web services.

Comment: Use the response from php web service and set it in intent.putString("url", <response variable from web service>);

Comment: what all parameters are you going to use in your url. Explain your question in detail so that we can help you better.

Comment: URL Example - "index.php?id=22". There may be multiple parameters can be passed along with url. So, how to read that value and from that load dynamic contents from database in android webView. Thank you.